# Pandas, reverse one hot encoding

Tags: python, pandas, one-hot-encoding

I one hot encoded some variable and after some computation I would like to retrieve the original one.

What I am doing is the following:

I filter the one hot encoded column names (they all start with the name of the original variable, let say `'mycol'`)

```
filter_col = [col for col in df if col.startswith('mycol')]
```

Then I can simply multiply the column names by the filtered variables.

```
X_test[filter_col]*filter_col
```

However, this leads to a sparse matrix. How do I create one single variable out of this? Summing doesn't work as the empty spaces are treated as numbers and doing this: `sum(X_test[filter_col]*filter_col)` I get

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'
```

Any suggestion on how to proceed? Is this even the best approach or is there some function out there doing exactly what I need?

As request, here is an example, taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30424537/3284713):

```
df= pd.DataFrame({ 
    'mycol':np.random.choice( ['panda','python','shark'], 10),
    })

df=pd.get_dummies(df)
```

Comment: Do you need `(X_test[filter_col]*filter_col).sum()` or `(X_test[filter_col]*filter_col).sum(axis=1)`?

Comment: Also if get all columns starting by string `mycol`, then also failed `X_test[filter_col]*filter_col`

Comment: Can you create some [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: `X_test[filter_col].idxmax(1).str.replace('mycol_', '')` ..?

Comment: @jezrael Your first comment is the solution: `(X_test[filter_col]*filter_col).sum(axis=1)`. Would you post it as answer so I can accept it?

Comment: @ChrisA Thanks Chris =) You went a step forward and also cleaned up the result

Comment: there is only one `1` per rows?

Comment: @jezrael yes, there is only one `1` per row.

Comment: ok, so never only `0`, always only one `1` per rows? If yes, then accepted solution working, else not.

Comment: added mcv example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you can use [`DataFrame.idxmax`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.idxmax.html) along `axis=1`. If necessary you can replace dummy prefix, with [`str.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html):

```
X_test[filter_col].idxmax(axis=1).str.replace('mycol_', '')
```

Answer (score 2):

If need sum values per rows:

```
(X_test[filter_col]*filter_col).sum(axis=1)
```

Solution if possible only `0` per rows or multiple `1` per rows:

```
X_test = pd.DataFrame({
         'mycolB':[0,1,1,0],
         'mycolC':[0,0,1,0],
         'mycolD':[1,0,0,0],

})


filter_col = [col for col in X_test if col.startswith('mycol')]
df = X_test[filter_col].dot(pd.Index(filter_col) + ', ' ).str.strip(', ')
print (df)
0            mycolD
1            mycolB
2    mycolB, mycolC
3                  
dtype: object
```